# How do I manually format dates in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I want to show a date like this 01/12/2015 as `151201`. I tried to do it with this formula: `=Date.Substring(8,2)+Date.Substring(3,4)+Date.Substring(0,2)` but it is not working. Could you please help me?

Comment: Sorry, the new text value should be "151201"

Answer (score 1):

Use this calculation instead: `=Date.ToString("yyMMdd")`

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports basic date and time formatting options similar to how this works in the [Microsoft .NET framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: GREAT!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: Glad this helped!  Please click on the checkmark next to answers on StackExchange that answer your original question.  This helps other users know that the answer is correct.